# expires header not working drupal

Tags: drupal, mod-expires, expires-header

I am setting expires header in .htaccess file as below

ExpiresActive On 
  ExpiresDefault A1209600

It works for all the files that are in document root, but I have a separate mounted drive which is used as drupal file system ( private ), where I store my jcarousel images and for these images the expires header are not working.

Comment: what server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You private file system will have its own .htaccess file created by Drupal. Try adding the same line there.

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
Deny from all
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks    

ExpiresActive On 
ExpiresDefault A1209600
```